# I want to display pdf on href in new tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, href, display

I am using php codeigniter. I want to display pdf on href in new tab please give me idea how to implement this?
I am trying to use folowing code but it's not giving me expected output. 
My path of pdf is correct  `<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf`

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf" target="_blank"><h3><Span>1. </Span>First PDF<span></h3></a>
```

Comment: So what is it doing? What is the unexpected result?? ___not giving expected result___ That is not very helpful

Comment: Look at the page source in your browser. Is there a `/` before `image/.....`

Comment: 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf"><h3><Span>1. </Span>First PDF<span></h3></a>`

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try this : 
`<a href="<?php echo base_url('images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf');?>"><h3><Span>1. </Span>First PDF<span></h3></a>`

OR

Remove '/' (slash) used before "images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf" : 
 
`<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>images/flash/flashnews/flash_01/first.pdf"><h3><Span>1. </Span>First PDF<span></h3></a>`